# Design of matrix of contrasts in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, linear-model, matrix, contrasts

I am doing some post-hoc comparisons (in lme4, but here I'll just present a simple linear model), and I am having a hard time making sure that I am building the right matrix of contrasts to test differences between some combinations of factors.

**Here is my model:**

```
dataset <- data.frame(response=rnorm(1200), factorX=rep(c("1", "2"), 600), factor2=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 400))

model <- lm(response ~ factorX*factor2,data = dataset)
```

In my dataset, I measured a response variable depending on two factors: factorX (which has 2 levels: 1 and 2, 1 being the reference level) and factor2 (which has 3 levels: A, B and C, A being the reference level).

**I get this model output:**

```
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        0.02918    0.07183   0.406    0.685
factorX2          -0.03780    0.10158  -0.372    0.710
factor2B           0.02027    0.10158   0.200    0.842
factor2C          -0.10972    0.10158  -1.080    0.280
factorX2:factor2B  0.01409    0.14366   0.098    0.922
factorX2:factor2C  0.08925    0.14366   0.621    0.535
```

**Question**:

I want to know if there is a significant difference between some combinations of factor levels, so I build the following contrasts, and wanted to know if they corresponded to the right comparisons:

`c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)` => factorX1_factor2A vs. factorX2_factor2C

`c(0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0)` => factorX1_factor2B vs. factorX2_factor2B

`c(0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1)` => factorX2_factor2B vs. factorX2_factor2C

`c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)` => factorX1_factor2A vs. factorX1_factor2C

`c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)` => factorX1_factor2A vs. factorX2_factor2A

Is it correct?!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at ``dataset``? Don't build it this way. If the number of factor levels had a common divisor (e.g. 2 and 4), some factor combinations (e.g. 2 and 1) would never occur. Have instead a look at the function ``model.matrix()``.

Comment: Hey, thanks. dataset doesn't matter though, it's just an example. What I really want to know is whether I understand correctly the way a matrix of contrasts is designed or not. Is it the correct sequences to test what I want to test?

Comment: Can you demonstrate exactly how you plan to use the vectors that you wrote to test contrasts, i.e. the actual code?

Comment: Using the package _multcomp_:

`contrast.matrix <- rbind(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), c(0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0))`
and then `glht(model, contrast.matrix)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your last 2 contrasts are right, but the first 3 are wrong.

We can verify this by figuring out the linear combinations of coefficients that give each group mean, and then constructing the desired contrasts by adding and subtracting these linear combinations to form new ones that test the hypotheses you're interested in.

Here are the linear combinations that give each group mean (note that I shortened "factor" to "fac" for both of the factor names):

```
group <- paste0(dataset$facX, dataset$fac2)
group <- aggregate(model.matrix(model) ~ group, FUN=mean)
rownames(group) <- group$group
(group <- group[,-1])
#    (Intercept) facX2 fac2B fac2C facX2:fac2B facX2:fac2C
# 1A           1     0     0     0           0           0
# 1B           1     0     1     0           0           0
# 1C           1     0     0     1           0           0
# 2A           1     1     0     0           0           0
# 2B           1     1     1     0           1           0
# 2C           1     1     0     1           0           1
```

So now we can construct the matrix of contrasts by adding and substracting the rows of the matrix above:

```
rbind(group["1A",] - group["2C",],
      group["1B",] - group["2B",],
      group["2B",] - group["2C",],
      group["1A",] - group["1C",],
      group["1A",] - group["2A",])
#     (Intercept) facX2 fac2B fac2C facX2:fac2B facX2:fac2C
# 1A            0    -1     0    -1           0          -1
# 1B            0    -1     0     0          -1           0
# 2B            0     0     1    -1           1          -1
# 1A1           0     0     0    -1           0           0
# 1A2           0    -1     0     0           0           0
```

As you can see, the last 2 rows match what you wrote in your question but the first 3 rows do not match.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jake! That's great! It's much more clear now, I had missed an obvious step. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Jake, I know this post is old, but i'm having the hard time finding the answer to a similar question. Let's say you wanted to compare two levels of one variable to the third level. Is it as simple as first adding the linear combination of the two levels, and then subtracting the third linear combination from them? My factor variable has 4 levels and I want to compare levels 3 and 4 to level 1.

Comment: Yes, except you don't *add* the linear combinations for levels 3 and 4, you *average* them. And then you subtract the linear combination for level 1.